# Data can not be intered to Database PHP -- AFTER EDITING --

Tags: php, mysql

This is my last question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233894/data-can-not-be-intered-to-database-php

I did some changes in both; the pages that has the text boxes and the action page.

In the first page, I made the text boxes have different names with each loop:

```
$count1=100;
$count2=200;
$count3=300;
$count4=400;

echo "<form action='ConfirmEnter.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>MidTerm</th>"; 
echo "<th>Project</th>"; 
echo "<th>Final</th>";
echo "<th>Total</th>". "</tr>";

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input name='".$count1."' readonly='readonly' value='". $row1['ID'] ."'  size=5/></td> "; 
echo "<td><input type='text' name='".$count2."' size=5 value='0.0' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='".$count3."' size=5 value='0.0' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='".$count4."' size=5 value='0.0' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
$count1++;
$count2++;
$count3++;
$count4++;
} 
echo "</table>"; 
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
echo "</form>";
```

In the action page:

```
$count=1;
$count1=100;
$count2=200;
$count3=300;
$count4=400;

function addtwo($a = 0.0 , $b = 0.0 , $c = 0.0)
   {
          return ($a + $b + $c);
   }

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
 { 
  $id[$count] = $_POST['$count1'];
  $mt[$count] = $_POST['$count2'];
  $pr[$count] = $_POST['$count3'];
  $fi = $_POST['$count4'];
  $tot[$count] = addtwo($mt[$count]+$pr[$count]+$fi);
  echo $fi;
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO Marks (ID, Name, MidTerm, Project, Final, Total)
  VALUES ('$id[$count]', 'EMPTY', '$mt[$count]', '$pr[$count]', '$fi', '$tot[$count]')");
  $count++;
  $count1++;
  $count2++;
  $count3++;
  $count4++;
  }
```

The problem is still the same. The data can not be inserted to the database. 
I tested each line by print it using echo statement and I finaaly discovered that when I print the statements of $_POST it doesn't print anything ( as you can see in the code there is echo $fi)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that ID is defined as key, so you can't insert another row with the same ID. When my guess is right, use [INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html)

But however, whenever an INSERT fails, mysql_error() can tell you why, so you should ask it.